# Populating months with values or '0' from mySQL database

Tags: php, arrays, database, loops, mysqli

Edit: As requested, an example of the layout of `transactions` table:

```
txn_id   rent_amount   late_fees   discount_amount   type   paid_on (timestamp)
1        100.00        25.00       0.00              C      2015-10-23 12:00:00
2        50.00         0.00        0.00              C      2015-11-06 12:00:00
3        50.00         0.00        10.00             C      2015-12-17 12:00:00
...
```

I have an SQLI query that adds and groups up numbers from a table by month. The column `paid_on` is a timestamp.

```
$getTotalList       = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *,(SUM(rent_amount)+SUM(late_fees)-SUM(discount_amount)) AS list FROM transaction GROUP BY month(paid_on)");
```

This exports the values per month for any month that has data into comma separated values using:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getTotalList)) { 
    echo $row["list"].','; 
}
```

This is the output, which end up being values from October - December:

```
125.00, 50.00, 40.00,
```

Id like to show a 0 for months that have no data. We've tried doing something along the lines of

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getTotalList)) { 
for($i=0;$i<12;$i++) {
    if ($row["list"] == 0) {
        echo "0";
    } else {
        echo $row["list"].', <br />';
    }
}
```

But it outputs each month's data 12 times, still with no 0's for empty months.

As suggested below, I've also tried using the `empty()` variable:

```
if (empty($row["list"])) {
    echo "0, ";
}
```

but I get the same result `125.00, 50.00, 40.00,`

How can I correct this so it shows:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 125.00, 50.00, 40.00,
```

Comment: Does other months have data in the table, I am guessing you are trying to determine that in code!

Comment: My assumption for the code repeated 12 times is because the for loop is looping the one month twelve times. Have you tried flipping the loops and seeing if the results are different?

Comment: @AmanuelNega The other months do not have data. So basically I am trying to state "if the month has data, show it, otherwise show 0"

Comment: @ArmandKarambasis The loop isnt really a big deal at the moment. I can always play around with that later. I mainly need to show 0 for months with no data. Thanks though!

Comment: Which means they won't be in the list, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

Your query should be like this:

```
$getTotalList = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *,(SUM(rent_amount)+SUM(late_fees)-SUM(discount_amount)) AS list, month(paid_on) AS month FROM transaction GROUP BY month(paid_on) ORDER BY month(paid_on)");
```

And your code should be like this:

```
$displayed = true;
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; ++$i){
    if($displayed){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($getTotalList);
    }
    if($i == $row['month']){
        echo $row['list'] . ", "; 
        $displayed = true;
    }else{
        echo "0, ";
        $displayed = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't have any effect on the result. I think the problem with this is that in the DB, January (for example) is not 0 or empty. It simply doesn't exist because there were no entries. Would I be correct in assuming that, or does `empty()` take that into consideration?

Comment: @PaulRuocco Please see the `Return Values` section in the [documentation of `empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). And what do you mean by *It simply doesn't exist because there were no entries.*? What exactly *list* column holds?

Comment: @PaulRuocco I've updated my answer. Please check if this is what you want.

Comment: The link you posted answered my question (thanks :)) - but to answer yours: basically, the only thing that defines the months are the timestamps of each transaction. So if a timestamp with January as the month doesnt exist, then January doesnt exist in the table.

Comment: @PaulRuocco Glad it helped you. :)

Comment: Well, it answerd my question about the `empty()` variable. I'm still not getting the desired result though. In my comment above, i mentioned that I'm basically trying to say "if the month has data, show it, otherwise show 0". The problem is there is no "0" or empty row in the DB for some months because there is no timestamp.

Comment: @PaulRuocco It would be helpful if you could update the question with table schema.

Comment: @PaulRuocco I've updated my entire answer. please test your application with the updated code.

Comment: @PaulRuocco Did you update the SQL query like I suggested?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I deleted my comment when I noticed i missed that part. I just tested it and it works like a charm. Thanks so much for your time!